# Looping between functions and storing results

Tags: javascript, json, function, for-loop, return

I would like produce a list of grouped JSON elements according to a specific criteria, but I am unable to make my loop work. 
The function should make groups of with 12 bottles and return a single JSON list. So in this example, the function should extract the 3 first items and then run again to extract the remaining ones. But I am looping forever... Thank you in advance,

```
var data = {
    "order": [
        { "product": "MAXIMUS", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "COLECCION", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "CABERNET FRANC", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "CHARDONNAY", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "SAUVIGNON BLANC", "quantity": "6" }
    ]
};

var qtd = data.order;
var size = qtd.length;
var addline = '';
var add = '';
var total = 0;
var i = 0;
var a = 0;
var c = '';

function MakeList(i, add) {
    for (i < 0; total < 12; i++) {
        total += parseInt(qtd[i].quantity);
        addline = addline + '{' + '"quantity": "' + qtd[i].quantity + ' units"},';
        i = i++;
        add = '{"Box of 12":[' + addline.slice(0, -1) + "]}";
    }
    return [i, add];
}

function BuildLabels(i, add) {
    for (i < 0; c = "true"; i++) {
        c = a[0] < size;
        a += MakeList(i, add);
        i = i++;
    }
    return a;
}

var results = BuildLabels(i, add);
output = { id: 3, results };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i < 0; c = "true"; i++)
```

something weird is happening here. You don't set any condition on cycle to stop, you just assign value "true" to `c`. Try to use `==` instead of `=`; also initialization looks strange - set `i` to `0`. Apparently, It will make the whole thing work (at least the loop will stop at some point), but in the end I get that the variable `results` is equal to `0`. There are other mistakes/weird stuff out there. Propably, you wanted to achieve something like this:

```js
var data = {
    "order": [
        { "product": "MAXIMUS", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "COLECCION", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "CABERNET FRANC", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "CHARDONNAY", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "SAUVIGNON BLANC", "quantity": "6" }
    ]
};

function MakeList(data) {
    var selected = [], bottlesNum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; bottlesNum < 12; i++) {
        selected.push(data.order[i]);
        bottlesNum += parseInt(data.order[i].quantity);
    }
    return selected;
}

    var results = MakeList(data);
    // now it is a JS object:
    console.log({ id: 3, results: results });
    // if you want it to be a JSON string, use JSON.stringify():
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ id: 3, results: results }));
```

check it out.

**UPDATE**

```js
var data = {
    "order": [
        { "product": "MAXIMUS", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "COLECCION", "quantity": "3" },
        { "product": "CABERNET FRANC", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "CHARDONNAY", "quantity": "6" },
        { "product": "SAUVIGNON BLANC", "quantity": "6" }
    ]
};

function makeGroup(data, max) {
    var selected = [], bottlesNum = 0;
    while(data.order.length) {
      if(bottlesNum + +data.order[0].quantity > max) break;
        var order = data.order.shift();
        bottlesNum += +order.quantity;  // casting to Number
        selected.push(order);
    }
    return selected;
}

function splitOrder(data, max) {
 while(data.order.length) {
    var results = makeGroup(data, max);
    if(!results.length) {
      console.log("Error: a product's quantity is greater than max. size of the group. Try to increase max. size of the group."); 
      break;
    }
    console.log({ results: results });
 }
}
// 2nd argument - max. size of the group. In case of 12 there will be 2 groups - of 3, 3, 6 and 6, 6 bottles
splitOrder(data, 12);

// Also notice that if max. size of the group is a changing value and can be set somehow to, lets say, 4 which is fewer than number of some products (6) in our order. So, it is impossible to complete such a task without taking some additional steps to handle this situation. For example, we could filter our data beforehand to exclude products with numbars greater than 4 and then form groups based on the rest of the data. Or we can treat products with number equal to 6 as if they satisfy our constraint etc.
```

Comment: Thank you very much curveball, its working perfectly for the 1st box, but how can I loop again to get the remaining 2 items? It should produce 2 boxes , one with 1st 3 items , 2nd with the last 2 ones.

Comment: ahh...ok. let me add a few lines and check the updated answer in a moment

Comment: @Deca F Lima done, check updated answer. It took a little bit more than a moment :)

Comment: that is so perfectly beautiful! It works great! Thank you ever so much! I can sleep now !

Comment: thank you so much for the improvements! You just read my thoughts! I indeed work with boxes of 6 and 12 bottles! Thank you so much!